# how to add matrix reading from .txt to the travelling salesmen problem code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm freshman to python . Need your help

I'm trynna read matrix from .txt and add it to the traveling salesmen problem code . Can you explain what do I do wrong?

Input.txt looks:

```
Place; date1;date2;date3
#1;65;27;16
#2;46;56;11
#3;36;14;28
```

## script

```
import csv 
f= open("input1.txt","r") 
sum=(1 for line in open("input1.txt","r")) 
print (sum) 
def Min(lst, myindex): 
    return min(x for idx, x in enumerate(lst) if idx != myindex) 

def Delete(matrix, index1, index2): 
    del matrix[index1]
    for i in matrix: 
        del i[index2] 
        return matrix 
 
n = sum 
matrix = [] 
H = 0 
PathLenght = 0 
Str = [] 
Stb = [] 
res = [] 
result = [] 
StartMatrix = [] 
for i in range(n): 
    Str.append(i) 
    Stb.append(i) 

for i in range(n): 
    matrix.append(map(float, row) for row in 
csv.reader(f,delimiter=";")) 
print (matrix) 
for i in range(n): 
    StartMatrix.append(matrix[i].copy()) 

for i in range(1,n): 
    matrix[i][i] = float('inf') 

while True: 
    for i in range(1,len(matrix)): 
    temp = min(matrix[i]) 
    H += temp 
    for j in range(1,len(matrix)): 
        matrix[i][j] -= temp 

for i in range(1,len(matrix)): 
    temp = min(row[i] for row in matrix) 
    H += temp 
    for j in range(1,len(matrix)): 
        matrix[j][i] -= temp 

NullMax = 0 
index1 = 0 
index2 = 0 
tmp = 0 
for i in range(1,len(matrix)): 
    for j in range(1,len(matrix)): 
        if matrix[i][j] == 0: 
            tmp = Min(matrix[i], j)+Min((row[j] for row in matrix), i) 
                if tmp >= NullMax: 
                    NullMax = tmp 
                    index1 = i 
                    index2 = j 
 
res.append(Str[index1]+1) 
res.append(Stb[index2]+1) 
oldIndex1 = Str[index1] 
oldIndex2 = Stb[index2] 
if oldIndex2 in Str and oldIndex1 in Stb: 
    NewIndex1 = Str.index(oldIndex2) 
    NewIndex2 = Stb.index(oldIndex1) 
    matrix[NewIndex1][NewIndex2] = float('inf') 
    del Str[index1] 
    del Stb[index2] 
    matrix = Delete(matrix, index1, index2) 
    while 1: 
        if len(matrix) == 1: 
            break 

for i in range(1, len(res)-1, 2): 
    if res.count(res[i]) < 2: 
        result.append(res[i]) 
        result.append(res[i+1]) 
        for i in range(1, len(res)-1, 2): 
            for j in range(1, len(res)-1, 2): 
                if result[len(result)-1] == res[j]: 
                    result.append(res[j]) 
                    result.append(res[j+1]) 
                    print(result) 

for i in range(1, len(result)-1, 2): 
    if i == len(result)-2: 
        PathLenght += StartMatrix[result[i]-1][result[i+1]-1] 
        PathLenght += StartMatrix[result[i+1]-1][result[1]-1] 
    else: 
        PathLenght += StartMatrix[result[i]-1][result[i+1]-1] 
        print(PathLenght) 
        input()
```

When I trynna check it shows

> <generator object  at 0x038341B0>
> [<generator object  at 0x038341B0>,<generator object  at 0x038341B0>,<generator object  at 0x038341B0>,<generator object  at 0x038341B0>]

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend use pandas to read csv files (dont forget set non-standard separator).
`df = pd.read_csv(file_name, sep=";")`

here's answer for your question:
https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/

You need to create generator before u will use it.

```
# def of generator
def my_gen():
    i = 0
    for i in range(5):
        yield i
        i+=1
# creating generator
gen = my_gen()

# method 1 - yields until the generator finishes 
for num in gen:
    # do something 

# method 2 - yields only once
next(gen)
```

EDIT
Some python tips

1. use snake_case style:
   `PathLenght += StartMatrix(...)` -> `path_lenght += start_matrix(...)`
2. use `extend` method instead of multiple `append`:
   `list_0.extend([item_0, item_1])`
3. use negative index:
   `my_list[len(my_list)-1]` <=> `my_list[-1]` (it also work for -2, -3 etc.)
4. other way to copy list:
   `my_list.copy()` <=> `my_list[:]` (returns sublist from first to last element)
5. u can use syntax like this:
   `var0 = var1 = var2 = 0`
   every above variable has value 0 but dont use it when u want to create some lists and other mutable objects. (https://medium.com/@meghamohan/mutable-and-immutable-side-of-python-c2145cf72747)